# how to update an 'eagertensor" object in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, eager-execution

How to update the variables from a keras sequential model (model.variables) if they are eagertensors?  When I try to assign to them I get an error that says the object has no attribute "assign".

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

"tensors" are not updatable in tensorflow, variables are. To update a variable use variable.assign.